# Why do functions containing `await` need to be `async`?

Tags: programming-languages, concurrency

From what I understand, `async`/`await` enables to avoid the "callback pyramid of doom".
Let's say that I have `funcA()`, `funcB()` and `funcC()` that are `async` functions, now if I do something like that:

```
func someFunction() -> T {
let myValueA = await funcA()
let myValueB = await funcB()
let myValueC = await funcC()
return doSomething(myValueA, myValueB, myValueC)
}
```

Why do some languages (for instance JavaScript) require you to annotate your function with `async` ?
What would be the issue issue if the function wasn't asynchronous? I mean, since the function already contains `await`s, can't it be already considered as a non blocking function ?

Thank you

Comment: No, a blocking function can easily call asynchronous functions and wait until they deliver their results. Absolutely a bad idea, but absolutely possible.

Comment: @gnasher729 Doesn't await forces the instruction to wait until the called function returns ?

Comment: Why are you asking us, and not the designers of those languages?

Comment: @Raphael Well, isn't that still a CS question?

Comment: Different languages don't necessarily handle async await the same way

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I don't think so. Implementation details of programming languages are almost always offtopic.

Comment: This may not be clear in my question, but this is about language design in general and not about some specific language.

Comment: Any question about JavaScript is not about CS ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `async` annotation changes the way the body of the function is interpreted. Now you can clearly infer that if the body contains `await`, it must be `async`, but there are a couple of reasons why it makes sense to require an annotation.

The primary reason is, frankly, likely clarity. C# popularized this syntax and is a language that emphasizes declaring intent. My understanding (from vague recollections of blog posts) is that the C# designers view the fact that they didn't do a similar thing for generator syntax (i.e. `yield`) as a mistake or at least unpleasant compromise. Note that in JavaScript you *do* need to indicate a function is a "generator function" in much the same way as `async`. At any rate, both `async`/`await` and `yield` lead to dramatically different semantics, and you probably want to be clear that that is intended and understood. (A minor factor for C# was to make the `await` keyword contextual to avoid backwards compatibility issues.)

As a more technical reason, `async` and JavaScript's `function*` change the behavior of a function even if you *don't* use `await`/`yield`. In C#, an `async` method with no `await` will run synchronously, but it will still package up the result in a `Task` object. Similarly, in JavaScript, a generator function with no `yield` still returns an empty `Iterable` rather than `undefined`. If the `async`/`function*` aspect was inferred from usage of `await`/`yield`, then in these cases you would need to explicitly create a `Task` or `Iterable`. This isn't so bad in C# where the type system will require this, but in JavaScript there's a much greater chance for uncaught errors. Regardless, it's also bad for exploration since commenting out a line of code might dramatically change the behavior and type of the function.